# How to hide scrollbar when Navigation drawer is open

Tags: html, css

I'm leaving the first post. I'd be happy if you help my code.
I'm making my homepage layout, But I was in trouble.

I want disable scrollbar of Main Contents Section when Navigation Drawer button is clicked.
I tried to `#drawer-toggle:checked~html{overflow:hidden}` but it's not working.

If you have any other way, please teach me.

```css
body,html{
 margin:0 auto;
 height:100%
}
footer{
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 text-align:center
}
footer,header{
 background:#ccc;
 display:table-row
}
header{
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 padding-left:50px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:7
}
main{
 background:#eee
}
#container{
 margin-top:50px
}
#drawer{
 background:#fff;
 height:100%;
 left:-300px;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 padding:10px;
 top:0;
 width:85%;
 max-width:250px;
 z-index:9
}
#drawer,#drawer-toggle-label{
 position:fixed
}
#drawer-toggle{
 display:none
}
#drawer-toggle:checked~#drawer{
 left:0;
 top:0
}
#drawer-toggle:checked~#drawer-toggle-label{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.54);
 height:100%;
 width:100%
}
#drawer-toggle-label{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 height:50px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:50px;
 z-index:8
}
#drawer-toggle-label:active{
 background:#5c6bc0
}
#drawer-toggle-label:before{
 background:#fff;
 box-shadow:0 5px 0 #fff,0 10px 0 #fff;
 content:'';
 height:2px;
 left:16px;
 position:absolute;
 top:19px;
 width:18px
}
#wrapper{
 display:table;
 width:100%;
 height:100%
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id=wrapper>
<header>Header</header>
<div id=container>
    <input type=checkbox id=drawer-toggle>
    <label for=drawer-toggle id=drawer-toggle-label></label>
    <nav id=drawer>
        Drawer
        <ul><li>Menu
            <li>Menu
            <li>Menu
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <center>
        <table style=height:1000px;width:640px;background:#fff>
            <tr><td style=vertical-align:top>Main Contents
        </table>
        </center>
    </main>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Vertical or horizontal scrolling bar? Also, apply apostrophes around your attribute values.

Comment: I don't want scroll Main Contents when Drawer is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hoping to achieve something with CSS that is called the *parent selector* which isn't available, you cannot select a parent element of the clicked element in pure CSS. Your `~` selector only selects siblings (elements with the same parent) in the code. Besides this, your code has some lacking apostrophes and unclosed tags. I've updated your code, and added a JavaScript solution on the go.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('drawer-toggle');
element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.toggle('hide-scroll');
})
```

```css
body, html {
margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
}

footer {
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center
}

footer, header {
background:#ccc;
display:table-row
}

header {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
padding-left:50px;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:7
}

main {
background:#eee
}

#container {
margin-top:50px
}

#drawer {
background:#fff;
height:100%;
left:-300px;
overflow-x:hidden;
padding:10px;
top:0;
width:85%;
max-width:250px;
z-index:9
}

#drawer, #drawer-toggle-label {
position:fixed
}

#drawer-toggle {
display:none
}

#drawer-toggle:checked~#drawer {
left:0;
top:0
}

#drawer-toggle:checked~#drawer-toggle-label {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.54);
height:100%;
width:100%
}

#drawer-toggle-label {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
height:50px;
left:0;
top:0;
width:50px;
z-index:8
}

#drawer-toggle-label:active {
background:#5c6bc0
}

#drawer-toggle-label:before {
background:#fff;
box-shadow:0 5px 0 #fff,0 10px 0 #fff;
content:'';
height:2px;
left:16px;
position: absolute;
top:19px;
width:18px
}

#wrapper {
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%
}

.hide-scroll {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<header>Header</header>
<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="drawer-toggle">
    <label for="drawer-toggle" id="drawer-toggle-label"></label>
    <nav id="drawer">
        Drawer
        <ul>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <center>
        <table style="height:1000px;width:640px;background:#fff">
            <tr><td style="vertical-align:top">Main Contents
        </table>
        </center>
    </main>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

When clicking the label, we toggle a class on the body which disables the overflow, thus disabling scrolling.